# How to update data shown on a visualization page with php

Tags: php, mysql

Being a complete noob, I'm trying to create a way for my php page to show all data registered in a database when the values of the columns "identity" and "idricovero" are the same ones used at the start of the session.
Currently it shows only the latest data entered, while I'd like the page to "update" with every new data.

Here's the code

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    require "connessione.php";
    $operatore="";
    session_start();
    if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) {$operatore = $_SESSION['username'];}
    $idpazok = $idricok = $cartellaok = 0;
    $identity = $idpaz = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    if (!empty($_GET['identity'])) {
    $identity = test_input($_GET['identity']);
    $idpazok = 1;
    }
        if (!empty($_GET['idricovero'])) {
            $idricovero = test_input($_GET['idricovero']);
            $idricok = 1;
        }
    }
    if ($idricok AND $idpazok) {
        //prendo i dati della cartella paziente
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Accertamentomirato WHERE `identity` = '".$identity."' AND idricovero = '".$idricovero."'";
        //echo "<h2>".$query."</h2>";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
    $dataorarilevazione = $row['dataorarilevazione'];
    $csm1 = $row['csm1'];
    $csm2 = $row['csm2'];
    $csm3 = $row['csm3'];
    $cartellaok=1;
        } else {
            echo "<h2 class=error> Cartella paziente non esistente</h2>";         //.mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($results);
    }

    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }

    if ($cartellaok) {
    echo "<h1>" . "ACCERTAMENTO MIRATO" . "</h1>";
    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<legend>".$datarilevazione. "</legend>";
    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<legend>".$orarilevazione."</legend>";
    echo "<table>";
    if (!empty($csm1)) {echo "<tr> " . "<td> " . "TEMPO DI REMPIMENTO         CAPILLARE: " . "</td> "  . "<td>".$csm1."</td> "  . "</tr>";}
    if (!empty($csm2)) {echo "<tr> " . "<td> " . "SENSIBILITÀ TATTILE: " . "        </td> "  . "<td>".$csm2."</td> "  . "</tr>";}
    if (!empty($csm3)) {echo "<tr> " . "<td> " . "MOBILITÀ DELLE ESTREMITÀ:         " . "</td> "  . "<td>".$csm3."</td> "  . "</tr>";}
    echo "<tr> " . "<td> " . "Operatore: " . "</td> "  . "<td>".$operatore."        </td> "  . "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</fieldset>";
    echo "</fieldset>";
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```